# Violation of PRIMARY KEY With User Registration in Authorization Server

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-data-jpa

A simple application is created by using `oauth2 password` flow. The Authorization Server is working as the identity provider and when a new user is registered then the `jwt` token should be received as a response.

### Relationships between entities

User (M) ------------------  Role (M)

Role (M) ------------------  Permission (M)

when I signup with a new user the following error has thrown

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-02275: such a referential constraint already exists in the table
```

**How can I resolve the primary key violation with JPA? If I use Native Hibernate API then we can use `session.merge()` but in JPA there is no option like that.**

### Request

```
{
    "userName": "Nafaz Benzema",
    "password": "stackoverflow",
    "email": "benz@gmail.com",
    "active": "y",
    "accNonExpired": "y",
    "credentialNonExpired": "y",
    "accNonLocked": "y",
    "roles" : [
        {
            "id": 101,
            "name": "ROLE_USER",
            "permissions": [
                {
                    "id": 10,
                    "name": "CAN_CREATE"
                },
                {
                    "id": 40,
                    "name": "CAN_READ"
                }
            ]

        },
         {
            "id": 102,
            "name": "ROLE_ADMIN",
            "permissions": [
                {
                    "id": 10,
                    "name": "CAN_CREATE"
                },
                {
                    "id": 40,
                    "name": "CAN_READ"
                },
                  {
                    "id": 20,
                    "name": "CAN_UPDATE"
                },
                  {
                    "id": 40,
                    "name": "CAN_DELETE"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

### Entity classes

*User class*

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER90",schema = Schema.TESTDB,uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(name = "userName",columnNames = "USER_NAME"),
        @UniqueConstraint(name = "email",columnNames = "EMAIL")
})
@Getter
@Setter
public class User {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "USER_ID_GEN",sequenceName = Schema.TESTDB+".USER_ID_SEQ",initialValue = 1003,allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "USER_ID_GEN",strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "USER_ID")
    private int userId;
    @Column(name = "USER_NAME",nullable = false)
    private String userName;
    @Column(name = "PASSWORD",nullable = false)
    private String password;
    @Column(name = "EMAIL",nullable = false)
    private String email;
    @Column(name = "ACTIVE",nullable = false)
    private String active;
    @Column(name = "ACC_NON_EXPIRED")
    private String accNonExpired;
    @Column(name = "CREDENTIAL_NON_EXPIRED")
    private String credentialNonExpired;
    @Column(name = "ACC_NON_LOCKED")
    private String accNonLocked;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "USER_ROLE",joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", referencedColumnName = "USER_ID")},
    inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID",referencedColumnName = "ID")})
    private Set<Role> roles;
}
```

*Role class*

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ROLE",schema = Schema.TESTDB,uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(name = "name",columnNames = "NAME")
})
@Getter
@Setter
public class Role {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private long id;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private ERole name;

    // bi-directional
   /* @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<User> users;*/

    // uni-directional
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "PERMISSION_ROLE",joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID",referencedColumnName = "ID")},
    inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "PERMISSION_ID",referencedColumnName = "ID")})
    private Set<Permission> permissions;
}
```

*Permission class*

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERMISSION",schema = Schema.TESTDB,uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(name = "name",columnNames = "NAME")
})
@Getter
@Setter
public class Permission {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private long id;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private EPermission name;

}
```

**Service class**

```
public Response userRegistration(SignupRequest signup) {


        if(!Objects.isNull(userDAO.findUserByEmail(signup.getEmail()).orElse(null)))
            throw new UserIsExistedException(String.format("User is existed with %s",signup.getEmail()));

       try {
            User user=new User();

            String password="{bcrypt}";

           password = password.concat(BCrypt.hashpw(signup.getPassword(),BCrypt.gensalt(12)));


            user.setUserName(signup.getUserName());
            user.setEmail(signup.getEmail());
            user.setPassword(password);
            user.setActive("y");
            user.setAccNonExpired("y");
            user.setCredentialNonExpired("y");
            user.setAccNonLocked("y");
            user.setRoles(signup.getRoles());


           Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

            user.getRoles().forEach(role->{
                 roles.add(role);
                Set<Permission> permissions=new HashSet<>();

                role.getPermissions().forEach(perm->{
                    permissions.add(perm);
                });

                role.setPermissions(permissions);

            });

           user.setRoles(roles);

           userDAO.save(user);


            LOGGER.info("user is saved and response is returned successfully");
           return new Response(user.getEmail(), authenticationProvider.obtainToken(user.getEmail(), user.getPassword()).toString());

        }catch (NumberFormatException ex){
            LOGGER.error("NumberFormat Exception");
            throw new NumberFormatException("NumberFormat Exception");
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            LOGGER.error("invalid username or password");
           throw new BadCredentialsException("invalid username or password",ex);
        }
    }
```

Note - **If you need more resource here GitHub link**

[github_link](https://github.com/Benzeman97/identity-provider)

**config file**

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl
    username: TESTDB
    password: 14292
    driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
    hibernate:
      naming:
        physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
      ddl-auto: update
```

Comment: 'such a referential constraint already exists in the table' means that your code is trying to alter a table, adding an already existing constraint. It shouldn't have anything to do with you trying to insert data into the DB. Are you sure this is the error you're getting? I would rather expect it to pop up during application startup

Comment: @crizzis I have added constraint key for Role and Permission tables but when I run mu application then another constraint key will be generated by `ddl-auto: update`.

Comment: `CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "alter table USER_ROLE add constraint FKkd5rdh39wm74eq1vb4x4658qv foreign key (USER_ID) references TESTDB.USER90"`

Comment: `Error executing DDL "alter table PERMISSION_ROLE add constraint FKnuawdx8hu9thrauk3o4i3j3wb foreign key (PERMISSION_ID) references TESTDB.PERMISSION" via JDBC Statement`

Comment: i updated config fila too

Comment: Does this attempt by Hibernate to re-add the constrant prevent your application from running? If not, you can ignore it; it is simply easier for Hibernate to try adding the constraint and fail than to search for an existing constraint. If somehow your authentication fails, you should be looking for another issue in the logs

Comment: give me a minute I will update the complete logs and share the link

Comment: [logs_of_application](https://gist.github.com/Benzeman97/ec01b9fbe37f6760d581fa24ea72968b)

Comment: Sorry took me a while to get a docker container run with oracle. FIrst check ur constrains in the database and also check the block from the roles as i run into issue when i try out your call.


`  user.getRoles()
                    .forEach(role -> {
                        Role roleObj = roleDAO.findById(role.getId()).orElse(role);
                        roles.add(roleObj);
                        Set<Permission> permissions = new HashSet<>(role.getPermissions());
                        role.setPermissions(permissions);
                    });`

Comment: It clearly says the error has thrown with `Identifier`.               `javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [com.benz.security.web.api.entity.Permission#40]`

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by changing the CascadeType.

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "USER_ROLE",joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", referencedColumnName = "USER_ID")},
    inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID",referencedColumnName = "ID")})
private Set<Role> roles;
```

when I use `CascadeType.ALL` then it gives priority to `PERSIST` (save) which throws Primary Key Violation in my case. When roles assigned to the user and if it is available in the role table then I need to `Merge` it rather than `Save`. So I have changed the `CascadeType` from `ALL` to `MERGE`.

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinTable(name = "USER_ROLE",joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", referencedColumnName = "USER_ID")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID",referencedColumnName = "ID")})
    private Set<Role> roles;
```